# How can I check if a string is a new line?

Tags: shell

I have `if test '\n' = "$line"` but this doesn't seem to catch the new lines. What is wrong in that code?

Comment: Check this out:- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27423/bash-test-for-newline

Comment: do you what to test if $line is just the `\n` char OR if it has a new-line at the end-of-the-line? Good luck.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem: what are you really doing?

Answer (score 3):

How about

```sh
if test $line = $'\n'
```

Comment: Does this return a boolean? Do I wrap this in another if conditional if I what some logic to occur in the case it is true?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing that `$line` is exactly a newline, you can do either of

```
test "$line" = $'\n'  # This is non-standard, and will only work in some shells
test "$line" = '
'                 # This (two-liner) will work in any shell
```

If you want to know if `$line` merely contains a newline (ie, it is at
least two lines long), you could do:

```
if echo "$line" | sed 1d | grep -q .; then
  echo line is at least 2 lines
fi
```